# Display Images after replaceWith jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery's replaceWith method on a div. Both divs' contents come from a Bing search so the two divs have the same tags. I am calling the following, and the replaceWith method successfully replaces all of the links and also loads the right links for the images. When I click on where the images should be, the links take me to the right page. However, none of the images show up. This all takes place in an iFrame:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:url,
    success:function(data){
        history.pushState(data, '', url);
        var html = $.parseHTML(data);
        console.log(html[11]);
        console.log(typeof(html[11]));
        var new_content = html[11];
        $("#b_content").replaceWith(new_content);
        $("#b_content").show();
        $("#iaplanner").show();
        $("img").show();
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So the images take up space but are not visible? Have you tried to right click -> Inspect Element to see where the images are pointing to?

Comment: Please post response you are getting from BING...

Comment: The images point to where they would if i just did the search regularly, so they are the right url's if that makes sense? What do you mean by response from Bing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the images I suppose. If that is the case, what everybody recommends is to attach a timestamp to the image source, something like:

```
/path/here/img.jpg?12345678
```

That way the browser refresh the image.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. `parseHTML(data)` won't load any javascript embedded in the html.  If that Bing page does some "on demand loading", it won't run.  Does the bing page work with javascript disabled?  Also check if the `<img>` tags are complete, or if they're waiting for that javascript code to finish them.
2. Maybe the server hosting those images doesn't like other non-bing pages to use them.  Check if your browser is actually sending the `GET` requests and what answer, if any, it gets.  Probably the server checks the `Referer:` header.

Comment: The Bing page does not work with javascript disabled. Is there any way to just execute the javascript in the div that I need to load? I tried changing the .parseHTML call to .parseHTML(data, document, true) but then the div no longer loads correctly

Comment: The ajax call actually makes the GET requests so the image data should be loaded the images just aren't displaying